error al iniciar servidor en mysql workbench Could not acquire management access for administration
tengo un problema con el programa de MySQL Workbench. El tema es que me aparece

Could not acquire management access for administration

estuve viendo en internet y una causa comun es porque el servicio de mysql no está iniciado, pero cuando voy a servicios para activarlo ni siquiera me aparece, lo reinstale 2 veces y nada. estoy buscando soluciones en youtube pero no encontre a nadie con mi mismo error. tengo un proyecto y no puedo avanzar :)


Añadiste las variables de entorno?

Dices que no ves un servicio de MySQL, entonces vuelve a instalarlo correctamente: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/install-mysql-windows/

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
